# Is it better to store pre-calculated data or post-calculated data?

Tags: database

If you have an equation `x + y = z` and you're interested in `z`. Would be better practice to store `z` alone or to store `x` and `y` only and then calculate `z` whenever you need it?

For example, lets say I want to calculate greenhouse gas emissions on a car from a starting point to any other point in time. I would need the tailpipe GHG emissions per km as well as the distance the car has driven.

GHG = `distance in km * GHG per km`

Do I store the distances and then generate the GHG emissions (sum of distances * GHG per km) or do I store incremental GHG emissions post-calculation?

Comment: If you only store the result in your example then if you ever try to deconstruct your emissions data you will be told that every vehicle has same level of emissions!

Comment: Those parameters which calculate the result vary from car to car hence there is no good reason not to store them

Comment: And if I may ask, would it be better to calculate them server side or client side? Assuming I'd like to be nice to my database.

Comment: These simple mathematical calculations are a no match for server side computation and even if you want to be nice to database you can still perform these calculations using your server side programming language itself but obviously it all depends on your application design. Don't see anything obviously wrong with client side as well.

Answer (score 0):

Totally it depends on your need. but there are some issue when you use different database systems/services.

If you use your own database (SQL/MongoDB/etc on your own server/machine), you can store raw data and calculate them on demand, by this way you will have always this ability to perform anything on your raw data.

But when you use database as service like Firebase or Mongo Atlas, you have to pay for each process you have. therefor it's better to store the result of a calculation if you only use the result calculation at the end.

**Some note about popular database services:**

**Firebase**: when you use it the only alternative is storing the result of a calculation because you cant make calculation queries on this system.

**Mongo Atlas**: this system gives you calculation ability on your queries, for example you can make a query to find all doc then perform this formula: [field3 = fieldA+Field2], then get the result. but you have to pay for the calculation process, and each time you made that query you will pay for that.